# Can the Kunen inconsistency (or the existence of Reinhardt cardinals) be 'properly formulated' in Ackermann set theory?

Tags: set-theory, mathematical-philosophy

In their paper "Generalizations of the Kunen Inconsistency" (arXiv:1106.1951v1 [math.LO]10 Jun. 2011), Hamkins, Kirmayer, and Perlmutter write the following:

> The first [metamathematical issue--my comment based on theirs'] concerns the fact that the Kunen inconsistency  is explicitly a second-order claim, as the purported embedding $j$ that it rules out would clearly be a proper class of some kind.  in particular, the statement of the Kunen inconsistency does not seem directly to be expressible in the usual first-order language of set theory, as it quantifies over second-order objects:  *"There is no $j$ such that...."*  So how and in which theory shall we take it as a precise mathematical claim.  Many large cardinal notions are characterized by second-order assertions that turn out to have first-order equivalent formulations, which can be treated in $ZFC$ [or $ZF$--my comment]...But it is easy to see that there can be no corresponding first-order of Reinhardt cardinals, since if $\kappa$ is the least cardinal with this property, then by elementarity $j({\kappa})$ will also be the least, an immediate contradiction.  More generally, here can be no consistent first order property $\varphi({\kappa})$ that implies $\kappa$ is Reinhardt, because if $\kappa$ is the least cardinal with that property, then by elementarity so is $j({\kappa})$, again a contradiction.  So there is no completely first-order account of the Reinhardt cardinal concept, and the issue is how how then we are to formalize Reinhardt cardinals and the Kunen inconsistency in some second-order manner.  Although there are a variety of satisfactory resolutions of this issue, aligning with the  various treatments of classes and proper classes that are available in set theory, it turns out that they are not equally efficacious, for some provide a greater substance for the Kunen inconsistency than others.

They continue:

> One traditional approach to classes in set theory, working in $ZFC$  is to understand all talk of classes as a substitute for the first-order definitions that might define them.  In this formulation, the Kunen inconsistency becomes a theorem scheme ["As the quantification $\forall$$j$ over classes $j$ cannot be formulated in $ZFC$, this result can only be regarded as a scheme of theorems, one for each $j$ [Kanamori04, p. 319]--my importing of a fragment of their footnote 1 into the quote], asserting that no formula defines (with parameters) a nontrivial elementary embedding of the universe to itself.  Thus, for each first-order formula $\psi$ in the language of set theory, we have the theorem that for no parameter $z$ does the relation $\psi$($x$, $y$, $z$) define a function $y$=$j$($x$) that is an elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$ [it should be noted that, in the wake of the Suzuki (1999) result, "No elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$ is definable from parameters" (not using Choice, and so holding for $ZF$), Prof Solovay (in his Thursday, Dec. 15, 2011 (13:13:44 EST) blog post on the $FOM$ website) declared the question "Is it provable in $ZF$ that there is no nontrivial elementary embedding $j$:$V$$\rightarrow$$V$" settled (i.e. that there is no such nontrivial elementary embedding) for $ZF$--my comment].  This is the approach used in [Kanamori97, Kanamori04].

So in what system of axiomatic set theory do the authors of this paper suggest that "the fuller power of the Kunen inconsistency seems to be revealed"? Their choices are $KM$, and $NGBC$ [one would suppose that $NGB$ without local choice would be their analogue for $ZF$--my comment].

However, $ZF$ has a natural class-theory analogue--Ackermann set theory.  It is interesting (for me, at least) for several reasons.  The first is that Regularity (Foundation) holds for sets, not classes (so that nontrivial elementary embeddings for classes might exist). Secondly, classes (subclasses of $V$) are first-order definable with parameters, so that the aforementioned result of Suzuki might hold.  Thirdly, since Reinhardt himself wrote his Doctoral Thesis on the following topic. "Ackermann's Set Theory Equals $ZF$", formulating results regarding Reinhardt cardinals or the Kunen inconsistency in Ackermann set theory might provide insights regarding both notions.

So, in light of the above, I ask the following questions:

Is Ackermann set theory a system in which the fuller power of the Kunen inconsistency (or Reinhardt cardinals) seems to be revealed?  Why, or why not?